# Nginx flooded by IP address that's not going away

Tags: nginx, security, iptables, flooding

We are using nginx and seem flooded by an IP address that that's not going away even after putting it in firewall and usng `tcpkill`.

```
$ netstat -tn 2>/dev/null | grep :80 | awk '{print $5}' | cut -d: -f1 | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | head
    22 66.135.60.154
    4 104.25.218.111
    3 66.249.64.6


$ sudo iptables -I INPUT -m iprange --src-range 66.135.60.0-66.135.60.255 -j DROP

$ sudo tcpkill -i eth0 host 66.135.60.154
```

After thus `netstat` still shows the IP address. Have tries restarting nginx several times but not helping.

Any idea?

Comment: So netstat shows that IP in it's list or is it actually a proxied ip and carried in the x-forwarded-for?

Comment: @Matt can't tell whether it's proxied. How do I identify that?

Comment: Is your server directly connected to the internet or behind a NAT device/firewall?  netstat -L should show the address you're trying to block.  If it's not there then you can't do what you're doing.

Comment: If you're still not sure, what is your IP address?  what does ifconfig show?

Comment: @Matt We are using `iptables` and not any particular firewall. `netstat -L` gives `netstat: invalid option -- 'L'`

Comment: sorry just netstat no options.  So used to typing -l

Comment: @Matt it's possible something else could be wrong with nginx. At this time we the IPs have disappeared but nginx is still not accessible. it gives **502 Bad Gateway** which might mean either something wrong with nginx itself or with php-pfm

Comment: Or a misconfiguration.  Are you sure 66.135.60.154 is not your own IP range?  Seems to resolve to a web page with the words Aljoumhouria.  Is that yours?

Comment: @Matt No it's not. But we managed to identify the problem. We had put some rules in the firewall that seemed to have annihilated nginx. We removed the rules and now nginx is working.